# Make Query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have some queries here with native procesdure can anyone help me to convert it to CODEIgniter style that saved in MODEL Folder.

Here my Query :

```html
SELECT
CONCAT(address.firstname,' ',
            address.lastname) AS `Name`,
address.email AS Email,
items.created_at AS Date,
items.`name` AS Description,
items.store_id AS Logon,
items.`name` AS Category,
items.store_id AS FeedbackDate,
items.sku AS ProductSearchcode,
items.order_id AS Orderref,
orders.grand_total
FROM sales_flat_order AS orders
      JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS items
      ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id
      LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS address
      ON orders.entity_id = address.parent_id
WHERE   
   items .created_at BETWEEN  '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-31'
  AND orders.status = 'complete'
```

I hope anyone can help me :)
Regards

Comment: you can directly use your query in this way : $query = "your sql query"; $db_query = $this->db->query($query);
        return $db_query->result_array();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All answer is correct, but batter is used with [Query Builder Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) like bellow :

```
$this->db->select("CONCAT(address.firstname,' ',address.lastname) AS `Name`,
address.email AS Email, items.created_at AS Date, items.`name` AS Description,
items.store_id AS Logon, items.`name` AS Category, items.store_id AS FeedbackDate,
items.sku AS ProductSearchcode, items.order_id AS Orderref, orders.grand_total");

$this->db->from("sales_flat_order AS orders");
$this->db->join("sales_flat_order_item AS items", "items.order_id = orders.entity_id");
$this->db->join("sales_flat_order_address AS address", "orders.entity_id = address.parent_id", "LEFT");
$this->db->where("items.created_at BETWEEN  '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-31'");
$this->db->where("orders.status", "complete");

$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
```

Comment: can you help me to display this query result , I have some stack here with Controllers and Views ?

Comment: can you take a look to my repositories https://github.com/ianicno/tci, and take a look to folder Controllers, Model , View , it's correct to display query resilt to table with pagination ?

Comment: where you call `sales_rpt()` method in your controller. and what you face problem?

Comment: any email that I can contact to you so we can efective to back and forth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128244/discussion-between-razib-al-mamun-and-riandy).

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter you can run your custom query using

> $this->db->query();

in case if you query is to complex like:

```
$this->db->query(" your query ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use your query in this way :

```
$query = "your sql query"; 
$db_query = $this->db->query($query); 
return $db_query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Join Query- Active Records

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result=$query->result_array();
```